# Restrict http access to Azure blobs

Tags: android, http, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-blob-storage

I have a MVC 5 internet application with a web api 2 web service that is hosted on Azure. In the MVC application, the user can upload files to Azure blob containers. Currently, once a blob has been created, anyone can access the http address for this blob.

I am also coding an android application that retrieves image urls from the web service, and then these images are displayed in the android application.

I want to restrict the access to these images to only the users of the android application.

Should I use Shared Access Signatures to restrict http access to the blobs so that only my android application has http access to the blobs? Should this be done in the web api 2 controller before the  JSON data is sent to the android application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use Shared Access Signatures to restrict http access to the
>   blobs so that only my android application has http access to the
>   blobs?

Yes. As of today, that would be the only way to restrict access to the blobs. Do ensure that blob container containing these blobs has `Private` ACL. Also when creating Shared Access Signature (SAS), make sure that the SAS is valid for a short duration of time so that even if a user shares the SAS URL somehow, the blob is not accessible after a certain period of time.

> Should this be done in the web api 2 controller before the JSON data
>   is sent to the android application?

Without knowing your application details, this is somewhat hard to answer but in general this should be the approach. Your WebAPI controller should return SAS URLs of the blobs.